# Unable to identify authentication-provider user-service-ref in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am implementing spring security in my project

In my DAO class I am defining the loadUserByUsername

my class is like

UserDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl {

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name)throws UsernameNotFoundException
{
  //implementation 
}
}
```

In Spring-security.xml

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="UserDAOImpl">
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

but when I run the program I am getting an error

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'UserDAOImpl' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'UserDAOImpl' is defined
```

Can anyone help me how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you define your UserDaoImpl bean at all in servlet-context.xml?

Comment: won't the framework automatically detect it I've given as @Repository
UserDaoImpl?

Comment: It will, but did you add `<context:component-scan base-package="your.repository.class.package" />` ?

Comment: well when I declare the bean explicity in servlet-context.xml it works fine `<bean id="userDAO" class="com.dao.UserDAOImpl"/>` but without it on giving the class name UserDAOImpl as `user-service-ref="UserDAOImpl"` it doesn't work. Note: the base-package path is correct.

Comment: What should be given here `user-service-ref="?"` when not declaring the bean explicitly in xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically beans that are component scanned are camel-cased starting with a lowercase character so the bean would exist in the application context as `userDAOImpl` (not `UserDAOImpl`)

change your `spring-security.xml` snippet to

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDAOImpl">
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

phew... got it working.

Moved

```
<context:component-scan base-package="app.com,app.com.controller,app.com.dao,app.com.service,app.com.model"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
            p:basename="messages"/>
```

from dispatcher-servlet to application-context.xml

@Service("userDAOImpl") annotation on class name

Would anyone care to tell why it started working?