# Cannot resolve reference to bean while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'

Tags: java, solr, spring-security

I'm doing my own custom security with Spring Security and a solr core, it seems like I did something wrong but I'm not sure what.

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'CustomUserDetails' is defined
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:231)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
```

This the `security-context.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled"></security:global-method-security>
    <security:http auto-config="true" realm="Protected Web"
        pattern="/**" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:csrf disabled="true" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/api/1.0/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            username-parameter="j_username" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            password-parameter="j_password" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1"
            default-target-url="/index" always-use-default-target="true" />

        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
            delete-cookies="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            logout-success-url="/login" />
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="2" />
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>



       <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="CustomUserDetails" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

The class `CustomUserDetails`:

```java
@Service
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StatusAppJob.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserAppRepository userAppRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        List<UsuarioApp> result =  getUserDetails(username);

        if(!result.isEmpty())
        {

        }
        else{
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " not found");
        }

        UserDetails user = new User(username, result.get(0).getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getAuthorities(result.get(0).getRol()));
             return user;

    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String rol) {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> auths = new java.util.ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rol));
        return auths;
    }

    public List<UsuarioApp> getUserDetails(String user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return userAppRepository.findUser(user);
    }

}
```

The `app-context.xml` file:

```xml
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
        <display-name>secturv2</display-name>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/solr-config.xml,
                /WEB-INF/Spring-Quartz.xml,
                /WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml,
                /WEB-INF/spring/postgres-config.xml  

            </param-value>
        </context-param>
    <!--,   /WEB-INF/spring/postgres-config.xml  -->
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

    <!--    Sesiones de Hibernate -->
        <filter>
            <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
                <param-value>sfTurismo</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <error-page>
            <error-code>401</error-code>
            <location>/error</location>
        </error-page>

        <error-page>
            <error-code>403</error-code>
            <location>/error</location>
        </error-page>

        <error-page>
            <error-code>500</error-code>
            <location>/error</location>
        </error-page>

    </web-app>
```

**EDIT:**

Added the `servlet-context.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="mx.sectur.turismo" />
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <resources location="/views/" mapping="/**" />

    <beans:bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="conversionService" />
    </beans:bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
                <beans:property name="maxPageSize" value="10"></beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
            <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
        </beans:bean>
    </interceptors>

</beans:beans>
```

Why I'm getting

> Cannot resolve reference to bean while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'"

message?

Comment: whats is package of CustomerUserDetails class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These issue is due to referencing bean using wrong name.

Please override the name of the bean created by @Service annotation like this

```
@Service("CustomUserDetails")
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetailsService
```

By default, Spring will lower case the first character of the component – from ‘CustomUserDetails’ to ‘customUserDetails’. And you can retrieve this component with name ‘customUserDetails’.

so you can also modify below code if you do not want to override default name as below

```
 <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetails" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Please refer [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/) link for better understanding this concept

Other thing that might be causing issue is you have defined annotation driven in servelet-xml which is in web application context where your service bean is getting initialized. but you have defined security-context in main application context. hence just create a file give any name to it and shift 
 to that file.

Comment: refer this link for similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744666/unable-to-identify-authentication-provider-user-service-ref-in-spring-security

Comment: look for updated answer. you are unknowingly got into this. try to understand the scope of main application context and servlet context.

Comment: wait, I'm a bit confused, i have to shift the annotation driven to another file?

Comment: Also move component scan to main application context. And the web appliction context i was refering to is also known as servlet context

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem once.

The application-context file should be present in the resources folder in order for the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to load the context config file.

Answer (score 1):

The class path resource of you bean is wrong or the file name is not properly mentioned.
In your case you have not mentioned the bean name and spring context is unable to autodetect it and  get this instance from the context.

There are two ways to do this

1. With Annotation

Use @service on top of the class which is used to auto detect the class like

```
@Service("BeanName") // so that spring context can autodetect it and we can get its instance from the context
class className{
//class members
//constructors
//methods
}
```

2. With XML

Mention bean class properly

```
<bean id="1" class="com.package.javafilename"></bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Spring but looks like your spring application-context file needs something like this-

```
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.package.CustomUserDetails "/>
```

Comment: i have this ´<context:component-scan base-package="mx.sectur.turismo" />´  in this file  ´<param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>´

Comment: Oh! But the snippet you posted for servlet file did not include that.